# d3 bar chart from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a barchart, but I cannot resolve its secondary function; updating with secondary data.

I make the bars with primary data from 2 separate arrays into an array like this;

```
labes = [label1, label2];
primarydata = [1,2]

data = [];
data = $.map(labels, function(v, i) {

                return [[" " + v, " " + primaryData[i]]];

             });
```

which gives output:

```
[["label1", "1"], ["label2", "2"]]
```

I then insert the data into an d3 bar chart.

```
var svg = d3.select($(svgobject).get(0)),
                margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
                width = $(svgobject).width() - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
                y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]),
                y1 = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

            var g = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
                return d[0];
            }));


            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                // parseInt needed here, or the scaling is wrong. Still scales though for some reason
                return parseInt(d[1]);
            })]);

// Inserts the x-axis line text
            g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
                .selectAll("text")
                .attr("y", 0)
                .attr("x", 8)
                .attr("dy", "1.75em")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(340)")
                .style("text-anchor", "end");

            // Inserts the y-axis line
            // d3.format(".2s"), formats the line fx from 1300 to 1.3 thousand
            g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10).tickFormat(d3.format("2.2s")))
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
                .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
                .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                .attr("text-anchor", "end");

            // Insert all the bars
            g.selectAll(".bar")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return x(d[0]);
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return y(d[1]);
                })
                .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", function (d) {
                    return height - y(d[1]);
                });
```

and this produces the barchart

However I want to with a push of a button put in comparable data like this;

```
secondaryData = [];

data = primaryData.concat(secondaryData).map(function(a, i) {
                 return [labels[i % 2], a.toString()];
             });
```

And then I am at a loss as how to proceed. My bar does not even show the full data from the array with primary and secondary data. How do I insert the secondaryData but differentiate it? So I can style it differently.

I have also tried making a y1 taking data from d[2], but have failed in doing so.

Comment: You should combine the 2 arrays and call the first function again to render them in the bar chart.

Comment: Thats what Im trying to do, but even that does not work. I rebuild the chart upon making the combined data array with both primary and secondary